# How to find out whats going wrong in HTMLUnitDriver/Firefox with a page that closes itself?

Tags: selenium, firefox, htmlunit-driver, auto-close

I am analysing websites often with Firefox (66) and it's Network Analysis which is very helpful.

Now I have a situation where I open a page and this page opens another one. Within this last page I fill in something and then pressing the submit button. The result is that this page closes and the previous page gets a refresh.

When I have open the network analysis on the last page, then the analyser will vanish at the moment the page vanishes - is there a way to see the response from this page before it vanishes?

The point is that I am writing a selenium test for the described scenario, but within selenium not only the last page is closed - the two last pages will be closed - which is not what I want.

So I am trying to find out if this is a bug in HTMlUnitDriver or if the browsers like firefox are handling things different (by ignoring a second close for example).

Sorry there is no code involved in this question.